# Internal Compiler Error with C++ in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, release

I updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 but now I am getting the following error when ever I compile a release configuration for 64 bit, everything works for 32 bit and/or debug builds.

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 246)
   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
    link!InvokeCompilerPass()+0x2d4bd
    link!DllGetC2Telemetry()+0xae663
```

The error occurs not for every of my projects but for some.

Simplifying the specified location is not really possible, the location where compiler is crashing is usually just a very simple one line function, also changing this code leads to the same error at a different location.  As far as I can guess it has to do something with optimization and inlining.  But changing optimization options didn't help either.

Can anyone point me to a direction how to locate the real problematic code or some compiler options to avoid this error?

I would like to not believe that that the update is broken.

Comment: report in on connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Comment: @magicandre1981 Looks to have been reported on connect already https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1767109/internal-error-compiling-stdafx-cpp and elsewhere in the comments at http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/12/01/visual-studio-2015-update-1-is-available.aspx?PageIndex=2. No resolution that I can see, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We encountered C1001 in one of our projects after upgrading to MSVC 2015 update 1.

Through trial-and-error, we've identified the `ClCompile/AssemblerOutput` property as the culprit in our case. Removing this property no longer caused C1001

Source: https://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/ticket/2580

Update April 6th 2016: I tried building this same project with MSVC 2015 Update 2 without the `ClCompile/AssemblerOutput` property removed and I no longer get C1001 when building this project. I think Update 2 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up at project optimization to Disabled (/Od), it may resolve the issue.

> To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development
>   environment
>
> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
> 2. Click the C/C++ folder.
> 3. Click the Optimization property page.
> 4. Modify the Optimization property.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafb762y.aspx

I hope my answer supports your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Repro compiling a JSON lib in Release|x64. Config was set on maximize speed (/O2), but General was using "No Whole Program Optimization".
Changing from "No Whole Program Optimization" to Use Link Time Code Generation (I believe the flag is /LTCG) build successfully.

Comment: Actually, it was also the
  C/C++, Output Files, Assembler Output 
which need to be on "No Listing”.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue while we were converting our company's codebase from VC10 to VC14.  In our case, the issue occurred when targeting x64 and SEH (`/EHa`) was enabled at the same time as Assembler Output was turned on.  The error appeared to happen in our case when the stream insertion operator (i.e., `std::cout::operator<<`) was called in the compiled code.

In our case, dynamically linking the CRT instead of statically linking it (i.e., `/MT` instead of `/MD`) appears to work around the issue without disabling assembler output.  This isn't the first issue that I've found with the statically-linked CRT (for example, it also caused missing cursors when resizing CPane windows in MFC).

This was reported to Microsoft (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2216490/compiler-crashes-at-string-stream-insertion-operator), but two and a half months later, it appears that they haven't even looked at it...

**Edit:** VS2015 Update 2 has, according to Micrsoft, fixed this issue.  It tested as fixed on our codebase.