# basic_timed_mutex.hpp(159): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler

Tags: visual-studio, boost, 64-bit, managed-c++

I have problem when I am building project in Visual Studio 2010 for 64bit. I couldn't able to build for 64bit with boost library, I am getting below error. I can build for 32bit but not for 64bit.

```
    \boost_1_49_0\boost\thread\win32\basic_timed_mutex.hpp(159): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\wvm\mdmiscw.c', line 2704)
5  To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
5>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
5>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
5>  The command exited with code 2.
```

It is pointing error to the below code and ofcourse I can't change the boost library. I am confused with this error

```
void unlock()
            {
                long const offset=lock_flag_value;
                long const old_count=BOOST_INTERLOCKED_EXCHANGE_ADD(&active_count,lock_flag_value);
                if(!(old_count&event_set_flag_value) && (old_count>offset))
                {
                    if(!win32::interlocked_bit_test_and_set(&active_count,event_set_flag_bit))
                    {
                        win32::SetEvent(get_event());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can you please help me,

Thank you

Edited :

I am not sure where the error but I think its in the boost libraries, there is a cpp file like

```
Class a::a(, point, )
{
}
```

and the "point" is a namespace  which is defined in a header file which is using boost libraries and it has following code

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>

    namespace point 
    {
// some work1
    void fun()
    {
    boost::unique_lock< boost::recursive_mutex > lck(*m_RedrawMutex);
// some work2
    }
// some work3
    }
```

Answer :
It finally worked !! After two days of search, I found another way.I just changed the order of include path in the project header where it was using boost basic_timed_mutex.hpp. I placed boost include path at the top and it worked. It's strange!!!

Comment: please post a minimal complete example that exhibits the problem - something we can compile and replicate. What do you think? That we're Supreme Intelligence Beings who can just omnisciently know your code, plus all the code in the compiler?

Comment: @richard I updated. Sorry if I couldn't able to reach you. I don't have that experience in c++

Comment: The code looks like managed c++, which can't reasonably be said to be c++. I've updated the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same issue myself - and it seems to be related to certain code-blocks in boost itself. It appears to be caused by a bug in the MSVC compiler toolchain.

Disabling optimisation appears to solve the issue for many users [As per this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafb762y.aspx) - [Source from MSDN suggesting this fix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y19zxzb2.aspx) [Souce on stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519080/2810883)

I wish I could present a logical cause, or bug report on the issue, but for myself the problem was solved by **upgrading to Boost 1.60**.

That said, other uses have reported that [trailing-slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17451979/2810883) are the cause!

## update:

After some browsing it appears this issue can be caused by everything from infinite-loops, though to templates types holding function pointers. and doesn't always list the actual-source of the error correctly (eg: it's not where the error message says it is). That said, disabling optimisation appears to solve the issue near universally - at the cost that your software may run slower.

Comment: Sure. I will try upgrading the boost and let you know. Thank you

Comment: @Raj Good luck, if that fails be sure to try the optimisation pragma: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx

Comment: thank you. I am not that experienced in c++. I am just building libraries for an application which contains more than 100 projects. I never used pragma before. I read that pragma should be used outside the function. Ofcourse I can't change anything in boost. I have to change just above, the function ( unlock() ) is called in the respective project where I am getting the error. Am I right ?

Comment: @Raj You should be able to put the pragma around the entire #include<boost/....> line, that will disable optimisation for that entire boost-header file.

Comment: Same error even for boost 1.60. Now I have to check with pragma,

Comment: I updated the code, can you please check it. Does that make sense ? Because its difficult for me, if I don't get to know the error itself

Comment: It finally worked !! After two days of searching I found another way.I just changed the order of include path in the project header where it was using   basic_timed_mutex.hpp. I placed this include path at the top and it worked.

Comment: @Raj Wow, that's a strange solution to a stranger error! Don't forget you can answer your own question on SO - it's always a great help to other users who may find a similar error in future.